# How to Checkout the source code from http link

Tags: svn, mercurial

I need to checkout the source code from the link "http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla2.0/source/modules/plugin/sdk/samples/basic/mac/" into my Mac System.

I have tried checking out this using TortoiseSVN, it failed to checkout like saying
could not connect to server("http://mxr.mozilla.org").

Even I hav installed mercurial for mac and used the command from terminal
"hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-2.0/ 20src", said "abort: error: Connection refused"

Has any one faced this problem or is there any solution to checkout the source code from the given link.

Comment: doesn't look like its meant for checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this yet but I think you can do:

`hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-2.0/modules/plugin/sdk/samples/basic/mac/`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,I have tried this right now but Terminal says "abort: error: Connection refused".

Answer (score 0):

Is this a git repository perhaps? What does it tell you if you navigate there?

(Just took a peek, this looks just like a plain directory with code files. Try sucking it down with wget or some such, or just downloading file by file.)